# qTip2 html content removal when hide event triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, qtip2

I want to set content of qTip2 with a div. The first show event (mouseover) shows the div correctly. However, after I trigger hide event (mouseout), the div is cleared and qTip2 shows a blank tooltip.
By using firebug, I noticed that as I mouseover, the div is copied to the qtip and after mouseout is triggered, it's gone forever.

jquery clone is an option, I tried that but my div consists of a DataTables object so the pagination stops working after clone.

I need to find a way to make qtip not remove the div item after it's copied to it. I need a hide/show mechanism I suppose. What do you suggest?

Thanks,

```
content: function()
{
     var qtipItem = this.id();
     var item = "#"+qtipItem+"_Detailed";
     var div_item = $("#detailedDiv").find(item);   
     return div_item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution but here is how I handled the issue:

Re-create the div that is destroyed by qtip hide event...

```
events: {
    hide: function(event, api) {
      if (qtipItem != null && detailedData != null && isqtipEmpty == false)      //re-create hidden(destroyed by qtip2) table
          contructDetailedRes(qtipItem, detailedData[qtipItem]);  
}
```

},